# When an idempotent element is irreducible

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with 1, and $e^2=e$ be an idempotent element of $R$. Recall that an irreducible idempotent is an idempotent $a$ for which $Ra $ is a simple $R$-module.

> Question: Is the following true: An  idempotent element $e$ of $R$ is irreducible if and only if the ring $Re $ is a field?

Comment: Seems so. I haven't checked the details carefully, but since $R$ is commutative, it seems like the $R$-submodules of $Re$ are just the ideals of $Re$, so $Re$ is a simple $R$-module if and only if it has only trivial ideals.

Comment: It's proven in one line in the [wikipedia page definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotent_(ring_theory)#Types_of_ring_idempotents) of 'irreducible idempotent':  "A right irreducible idempotent is an idempotent a for which aR is a simple module. By Schur's lemma, EndR(aR) = aRa is a division ring". Perhaps next time some background research is in order first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, suppose that $e$ is an irreducible idempotent. We are going to show that $Re$ is a field with neutral $e$. Let $x$ a non zero element of $R$
 The submodule of $Re$ generated by $xe$ is $Re$. So there exists $y$ such that $yxe=e=yexe$. We deduce that the inverse of $xe$ is $ye$.